# Cannot create virtual environments anymore

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

This was my first time using python virtual environment. I usually use anaconda environments.

So I did

```
python3 -m venv ~/.flask-ml-azure
source ~/.flask-ml-azure/bin/activate
```

Then I tried to do the things specified [here](https://github.com/noahgift/flask-ml-azure-serverless) but there were some problems with libraries.
Anyway, I tried to do everything again so I did

```
deactivate
rm -r ~/.flask-ml-azure/
```

And I thought, "well now I can start again!"

but now when I do

```
python3 -m venv ~/.flask-ml-azure
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt install python3.8-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/me/.flask-ml-azure/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

What happened? What did I erase without noticing?

Answer (score 1):

did you try to install python venv ?

```
apt install python3.8-venv
```

according to the error message you install the python3-venv using the provided command to be able to create venv on Debian/Ubuntu systems

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem by doing `sudo apt install python3.8-venv`. However I wonder how did I destroy this in the first place?(I could do it in the beginning) And how do I erase *safely* a virtual environment I create??

Comment: well you did the normal way of removing  a venv by deactivating then deleting not sure why the problem happened but personally i like to use `mkvirtualenv` library to manage my venv since it is easy to use
when using this library run this command `rmvirtualenv ENVNAME` and your venv will be removed safely